# Fast alternative to str(huuuge_integer)

Tags: python, string, formatting

im currently calculating repeating sequences in the number Pi using a string of the numbers of Pi combined with string.count(string). (I was doing this just for fun today because it seemed interesting to me)

First step of my work is to get the first Million Numbers of Pi. 
This is pretty easy by using

```
from sympy.mpmath import mp
```

The next step is to format that into a string using the command

```
stringPi = str(integerPi)
```

and after that I iterate through that string counting re-occuring sequences.

The part where I have problems is the second & third one - formatting the incredible huge number of 1million characters into a string takes forever. 
Also the execution of

```
 amountOfSequence= pi.count(Sequence)
```

takes its time as it is done A LOT.

I dont think there is a faster approach for the .count(object) step, but is there a faster alternative way of converting a huuuuuge number into a string than using the str(integer) method?

Comment: `I dont think there is a faster approach for the .count(object) step` - actually, that could be optimized quite a bit, for example, with a [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). You'll take a performance hit implementing that in pure Python, though.

Comment: I read the article on the suffix array, but I dont get how it can be applied to my "problem": as I am not only looking for a suffix, but also for a sequence that repeats in pi that lies in the middle of the number. e.g: number: 12345678, I also want to look for re-occurences of 4567. suffix arrays only sort up to the end of the number, not interrupting in the middle.

Comment: You can use a binary search to figure out how many suffixes of the string start with your sequence. That's your count.

Comment: aaah, now I get it. Thanks! Still won't solve my str(integer) problem though ;)

Comment: You can try turning a formula for [finding digits of pi](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20010.5.shtml) into a generator. I'm not sure this will actually be faster, but you could keep doing it forever and maybe gain a little if you keep anything currently in memory less than your L1 dcache size.

Comment: the problem is not having to calculate the numbers, but to format them into a string... I dont think calculating the numbers and adding them to a string will be a lot faster than using the str() method. Calculating the 1st million numbers by using the command I wrote in the post takes about a second.